# Google Sheets App Script to remove Bracketed word from String

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pattern-matching

Hmm, I can't find the man page for 'replace' in Googles App scripts, I only see 'replaceText'. Anyway, from what I gather from the SO posts, the below should work, hopefully someone can spot it easily.

The String in the Cell is "[pro] all, everybody" and I want to remove the bracketed word '[pro]' so the result is 'all, everybody'.

It does work just fine with:

```
Cell = Cell.toString().replace("\[pro\]","");
```

but when I try to make it generic, it fails with all these (not sure what the pattern matching rules are, thus the question for the man page):

```
Cell = Cell.toString().replace("\[pr.\]","");
Cell = Cell.toString().replace("\[pr.*\]","");
Cell = Cell.toString().replace("\[.*\]","");
```

they should work, no ? What am I missing ?

Also, how would I use 'replaceText', I can't seem to apply it directly to the 'Cell' object.

Comment: I believe replace is a method for a javascript string.  You might like to take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).  Consider the difference between using a string as opposed to a regular expresssion.

Comment: Well, the fix should look like `Cell = Cell.toString().replace(/\[pr[^\]]*]/,"");`.

Comment: @Cooper thanks for the pointer, so App Scripts is based on JavaScript ? Didn't know, not sure why they don't list 'replace' in the App Scripts Docu pages. Wiktor thanks a bunch, worked like a charm !

Comment: The documentation states: `Apps Script is based on JavaScript 1.6, plus a few features from 1.7 and 1.8. Many basic JavaScript features are thus available in addition to the built-in and advanced Google services: you can use common objects like Array, Date, RegExp, and so forth, as well as the Math and Object global objects.` [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `String#replace` is a JavaScript function where you need to use a regex with a regex literal notation or with `new RegExp("pattern", "modifiers")` constructor notation:

```
Cell = Cell.toString().replace(/\[pr[^\]]*]/,"");
```

When using a regex literal, backslashes are treated as literal backslashes, and `/\d/` matches a digit. The constructor notation equivalent is `new RegExp("\\d")`.

The `/\[pr[^\]]*]/` regex matches the first instance of:

- `\[pr` - literal substring `[pr`
- `[^\]]*` - 0+ chars other than `]`
- `]` - a literal `]` symbol.

And replaces with an empty string.

Comment: great ! out of curiosity, why do I need to escape the first '[' and not the last ']' ? This worked for me as a generic solution: replace(/\[\S*\]/,""). Also, is App Script 100% JS ?

Comment: The `]` that is outside a character class does not have to be escaped, the regex engine always knows what it is, a special or a literal `]` symbol. Apps Script use JavaScript. However, it is just a subpart of the language, e.g. you can't just use DOM parsing as you would in plain JS.

Comment: Since you're already on a roll, could I have done the same with 'replaceText' ?-)

Comment: I am sorry, it is 1:00 AM here, I need to have some sleep. Not sure how you tried it. Note the `replaceText` regex is powered by the Re2, not JS, regex library.